# Error in puppet : File[...] doesn't seem to be in the catalog

Tags: cron, puppet, manifest

I want to add successive crons via puppet, first one to set as each 10 minutes, and the 2nd one to run in Sunday 7:00PM.

The first cron in puppet is working properly, but the 2nd one shows the below error:
"Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid relationship: Cron[notifyinactivetargetweekly] { require => File[...weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh] }, because File[...weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh] doesn't seem to be in the catalog
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run"

Below are the manifest code.

```
cron { 'firstcron':
    command => "${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}/firstcron.sh ${scmphptpl::Environment} ${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}",
    require => File["${scmdemophp::DocRootDir}/firstcron.sh"],
    minute  => '*/10',
    environment=>["COMPOSER_HOME=${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}",
                    "SYMFONY_ENV=${scmphptpl::Environment}",
                    "SYMFONY_DEBUG=${scmphptpl::Debug}",
                    "PATH=/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin/:/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin/"
                ],

}->
cron { 'weeklynotifyinactivejob':
    command => "${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh ${scmphptpl::Environment} ${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}",
    require => File["${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh"],
    minute  => '00',
    hour  => '19',
    weekday  => 'Sunday',
    environment=>["COMPOSER_HOME=${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}",
                    "SYMFONY_ENV=${scmphptpl::Environment}",
                    "SYMFONY_DEBUG=${scmphptpl::Debug}",
                    "PATH=/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin/:/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin/"
                ],

}->
```

The hieradata consists the below classloading:

```
classes:
  - scmphptpl::myprojectdeploy
```

the init.pp of myprojectdeploy consists:

```
class scmphptpl {
    $DocRootDir = "/app/code"
```

and I checked that the file "/app/code/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh" exists.

UPDATES:

I have created the same, but for some reason the cron is not running as per timing:

```
file { "${DocRootDir}/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh":
  ensure  => file,
  content => "... whatever's in the file, or use a template/source ...",
}->
cron { 'notifyinactivetargetweekly':
    command => "${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh ${scmphptpl::Environment} ${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}",
    require => File["${scmdemophp::DocRootDir}/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh"],
    minute  => '*/15',
    environment=>["COMPOSER_HOME=${scmphptpl::DocRootDir}",
                    "SYMFONY_ENV=${scmphptpl::Environment}",
                    "SYMFONY_DEBUG=${scmphptpl::Debug}",
                    "PATH=/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin/:/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin/"
                ],

}
```

but its not running after 15 minutes, need help

1. The puppet log says:
   File[/app/code/edlconsole/firstcron.sh]/mode: mode changed '0664' to '0751'
2. but it does not showing the same for 
   File[/app/code/edlconsole/weeklynotifyinactivejob.sh]/mode: mode changed '0664' to '0751'
3. frequency changes are reflecting though

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show the file that Puppet is reporting is missing. Do you actually have it in your manifest? If so, include it in the question. If it's in another class then show how it's laid out.

Comment: The hieradata consists the classloading:
classes:
  - scmdemophp::edsconsoledeploy
The init.pp consists:
class scmdemophp {
   $DocRootDir = "/app/code/"
and I have verified that the file: /app/code/notifyinactivetargetweekly.sh exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `require`, `before`, `subscribe` or `notify` parameter to say that a resource is related to a file or other resource must contain a valid reference.

The `require` parameter you're using is requiring a particular file *resource* defined in your Puppet manifests, not necessarily a file on the server itself. This is what it means by the file not being *in the catalog* (the catalog is built from manifests).

```
require => File["${scmdemophp::DocRootDir}/notifyinactivetargetweekly.sh"],
```

This means that there must be a File resource called `/app/code/notifyinactivetargetweekly.sh` defined in your manifest, e.g. in the scmdemophp class you could have:

```
file { "${DocRootDir}/notifyinactivetargetweekly.sh":
  ensure  => file,
  content => "... whatever's in the file, or use a template/source ...",
}
```

And then the `require` dependency can be resolved.

If you don't wish to manage the file with Puppet, then simply leave the `require` parameter out.